# Holding intermediate variables constant in partial derivative chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

**Update**: I have realised that I did not really understand what I was asking, so I have significantly updated my question, and have provided my own answer below.

$ f(x_1, ..., x_n) $ is a function explicitly dependent on functions $x_i$. The total derivative with respect to the independent variable $y$ (that $f$ depends on implicitly through the intermediate variables $x_i$) is $ \frac{d f}{d y} = \sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y}$. It seems that one could perform this derivative in two different ways:

1. $\sum_i \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right|_{x_{j\neq i}}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y}$
2. $\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\left.\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y}\right|_{x_{j\neq i}}$

where $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right|_{x_{j\neq i}}$ means the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_i$ while holding all of the other $x_{j \neq i}$ fixed.

For example, let's say $f = 2x_1 + 3x_2$, $x_1 = 4y + 5x_2$, $x_2 = 6y$. Then:

$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\right|_{x_2} = 2$

$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right|_{x_1} = 3$

$\left.\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y}\right|_{x_2} = 4$

$\left.\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y}\right|_{x_1} = 6$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 2 $

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 3 + 2*5 = 13$

$\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y} = 4 + 5*6 = 34$

$\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y} = 6 $

Approach 1 above gives $2*34 + 3*6 = 86$.

Approach 2 above gives $2*4 + 13*6 = 86$.

Are both of these approaches always valid?

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$? What variable is being kept fixed for you to be taking a partial derivative?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I have rewritten the question so that it hopefully now makes sense.

Comment: You have used rather strange definitions for $x_i$ in the examples given. For instance, where you claim $\frac{df}{dx_1}=2$, this is actually taking a partial derivative, not a total derivative. What this should be is $$\frac{df}{dx_1}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\frac{dx_2}{dx_1}=2+3\cdot\frac{6}{34}=\frac{86}{34}$$ The answer I gave below still holds - there is no difference between $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}$ in the case when $x$ is a function of $y$.

Comment: I am embarrassed to keep asking what are probably silly questions, but I'm afraid I am rather confused by a number of things you said.Why is my definition of $x_i$ strange? They are simply functions. In my example, and the general situation I am describing, they are functions that only depend explicitly on $y$ and other $x_i$s.

Comment: I see that my calculation of $\frac{df}{dx_1}$ was indeed incorrect. I still think there might be a valid idea here, though: changes caused by explicit dependencies on $y$ are captured by the partial derivatives, and changes caused by implicit dependencies are captured by the total derivatives. Let's replace my $x_1$ by $x_1= 5x_2$. Now $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y}=0$, so the first term in my question's final equation is 0, but the change in $f$ due to changes in $y$ through $x_1$'s dependence on $x_2$ is still captured by the total derivative in the second term in that equation.

Comment: When calculating $\frac{df}{dx_1}$, I am treating $x_1$ as a simple variable, so I get 2: if $x_1$ changed, how would that affect $f$. In my proposed equation, this gets multiplied by how much $x_1$ would change if any $y$s it explicitly depends on changed. This doesn't include changes caused by $x_1$'s implicit dependence on $y$ through $x_2$, but that is captured by the second term in my proposed equation. Since $f$ depends explicitly on every $x_i$, and every $x_i$ only depends explicitly on other $x_i$s and $y$, I think every change in $f$ caused by a change in $y$ should be accounted for.

Comment: Don't worry, there's no such thing as a silly question. I said your definition of $x_i$ was strange because, in particular, you could have written $x_1=34y$ or $x_1=\frac{34}{6} x_2$, or any different number of ways. It makes sense to not mix both $x_2$ and $y$ in this, and just use one or the other. But this shouldn't change the answer.

Comment: Moreover, you computed $$\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y}=4$$This use of partial derivative implies some quantity is being kept fixed. $x_1$ depends on only $y$ and $x_2$. So this must suggest that $x_2$ is being kept fixed - but if $x_2$ is kept fixed, then $y$ is being kept fixed. Do you see the issue with writing partial derivatives of $x$, when it is a function of just $y$?

Comment: I think I need to learn more about this before I really know how to express what I am asking, so I'll mark the question as answered for now (hopefully not against the guidelines). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, I will perhaps ask one more question: In [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Differentiation_with_indirect_dependencies) $f$ is really only a function of $x$, but they still calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. This implies that they keep $x$ fixed, but if they keep $x$ fixed, then they are also keeping $y$ fixed, similar to the situation you describe. Is there a difference that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easiest to understand this by visualising a dependency branch diagram. $f$ depends on the $x_i$s, so it is connected to all of them (I'll call these the first branches), then there are dependencies between the $x_i$s, so some of those are connected (second branches), and then the $x_i$s also depend on $y$ (third branches). The difference between approaches 1 and 2 is whether the second branches are included in the first factor $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)$ or the second $\left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y}\right)$. It doesn't matter which they are included in, as long as they are included once and only once.

Answer (score 0):

We take partial derivatives of the function $f$ because it depends on multiple variables, so we want to know how it varies with respect to just one of these, while keeping the others fixed. When we have $x=x(y)$, it does not make sense to take a partial derivative of this, since it depends on only one variable, there is nothing else to fix. So $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}= \frac{dx}{dy}$. This changes your result to $$\frac{df}{dy}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}$$which is, of course, true - it's just the chain rule.